# How to prevent Excel Save Changes dialog box only when certain actions were performed in the workbook

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling

I have a macro that can be enabled/disabled according to a Toggle button on my custom ribbon tab in excel

[image: Toggled]

When toggled the macro runs, creating a comment for whichever cell is selected and displaying the character and word counts for the contents of that cell in that comment and also on the Statusbar. I made it resource friendly by only keeping the comment for the current cell and deleting it once another cell is selected

[image: Cell Stats]

After the user is done checking whatever cells they wanted to check the stats of they can disable the feature by toggling the button off, at which points comments are again deleted. This all works perfectly and as planned. But, here's where I have an issue.

**My Code:**

*ThisWorkbook* Module:

```
'Used an instance of app instead of application because this will be implemented inside/from an add-in)       
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not buttonToggled Then Exit Sub 'Set from other sub using global declared variable
    'Use target(1,1) because you will do something based on the contents of a
    'single cell -- the first cell in the range
    Sh.UsedRange.ClearComments
    If Intersect(Target(1, 1), Sh.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '------>
    ' carry on from here
    Dim charcount As Integer: charcount = Len(Target(1, 1))
    Dim wdcount As Integer: wdcount = UBound(Split(Target(1, 1).Value, " "), 1) + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Character Count: " & charcount & "  |  Word Count: " & wdcount
    Target(1, 1).AddComment "Character Count: " & charcount & vbNewLine & "Word Count: " & wdcount
    Target(1, 1).Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
End Sub
```

*Regular Module:*

```
Public buttonToggled As Boolean
Sub ToggleTest(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
    If pressed Then
        buttonToggled = True
    Else
        buttonToggled = False
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearComments
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**My Problem:**

If the user uses this feature, even for just one cell (since the comment is created and deleted) they're prompted with a *Save Changes?* dialog box upon closing the file even if they made no other changes.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there a way to not display the *Save Changes?* dialog box *only* when the only thing that was "changed" was comments being automatically added & deleted by the macro?

   - I need the dialog box to show whenever other changes are made *along with* the automatic adding & deleting of comments and also anytime the user just makes changes (and doesn't enable the macro)
2. If this isn't possible, what would you suggest I do as a workaround/adjustment?

## **--Updated to include implementation of method in answer--**

Thanks to the answer provided below I've been able to achieve my objective.

*ThisWorkbook* Module:

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    saveStatus = ActiveWorkbook.Saved
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearComments
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = saveStatus
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    saveStatus = ActiveWorkbook.Saved
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearComments
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = saveStatus
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not buttonToggled Then Exit Sub 'Set from OnHoverCellLength sub using global declared variable
    'Use target(1,1) because you will do something based on the contents of a
    'single cell -- the first cell in the range
    saveStatus = ActiveWorkbook.Saved
    Sh.UsedRange.ClearComments
    If Intersect(Target(1, 1), Sh.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '------>
    ' carry on from here
    Dim charcount As Integer: charcount = Len(Target(1, 1))
    Dim wdcount As Integer: wdcount = UBound(Split(Target(1, 1).Value, " "), 1) + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Character Count: " & charcount & "  |  Word Count: " & wdcount
    Target(1, 1).AddComment "Character Count: " & charcount & vbNewLine & "Word Count: " & wdcount
    Target(1, 1).Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = saveStatus
End Sub
```

*Regular Module:*

```
Public buttonToggled As Boolean, saveStatus As Boolean
Sub ToggleTest(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
    If pressed Then
        buttonToggled = True
    Else
        buttonToggled = False
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearComments
        Application.StatusBar = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = saveStatus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not be too easy I think. Pretty much all you can do is check the workbook's `Saved` property - that will be False whenever an update has been made and the workbook not yet saved, but you have no way to tell if that flag was set to False as a result of your code (unless it happens always to be True when the user runs your code, in which case you can set it to back to True when you're done).  However, if it's False you can't very well set it to True since that might result in your user's changes not being saved when they close the workbook.

Comment: Please don't use the [macros] tag - read its description!

Comment: Sorry about that @vacip, I have removed the tag.

Comment: @TimWilliams that's what I was thinking. So, I'm kind of at a loss as to what to do in this situation. I wish there were a way to recognize if comments were the only changes made. What would you suggest I do instead? Any ideas?

Comment: If Saved is True before adding comments, set it back to True after that run.  Similarly, if it's True before removing comments, you can also reset it then.  If it's ever False when you start a run you'll have to leave it as-is.  I think that's the best you can do.

Comment: Huh.  I guess it was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not a compromise solution or "the best you can do;" it preserves the workbook's status as if your comments business never happened.

1. Create a module level boolean variable that is visible to your routine(s) that toggle the functionality on and off and create/remove the comments; this variable's value must be preserved even after the execution of the routine(s).
2. Before creating the comment, save the value of `<Workbook Object>.Saved` into the boolean variable. After removing the comment, update `<Workbook Object>.Saved` to the value in your boolean variable.

If you're making any changes to the workbook when you toggle the macro on/off, you can use the same strategy. You don't have to worry about what `<Workbook Object>.Saved` is at any time.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sharing this method with me. This is definitely a useful bit of info. I've updated my question with my before and after code for future user to be able to use it as an example of how to implement your method should they need one. Thanks again!

Comment: One hopes more people will follow through and bring closure to a question like this.

Comment: I make it a point to follow-up whenever I can because I know there are so many people on here that don't bother responding or even touching the question after they find or are given a working answer. So, I'm right there with you in agreement.